# OpenGL ES 2.0 render to texture bug on ARM MALI gpu

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, render-to-texture, mali

Hy,
I'm developing an app on android and I'm in the testing phase and I'm trying it out on different devices. I developed the app on a nexus 7.

When I run it on a arm mali gpu device the rendered textrue starts to blink / lagg like crazy.
I use GLES20.GL_POINTS in the generated texture if I set the point size to 1 it blinks and it looks like there are artifacts in it, and if I set the point size to a bigger number like 10 it "laggs" meaning sometimes it shows a texture from a earlyer rendering.

Any idea what could cause this ?

```
private void setupRenderToTexture() {
    fb = new int[1];
    depthRb = new int[1];
    renderTex = new int[2];
    // generate
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fb, 0);
    GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, depthRb, 0);
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, renderTex, 0);
    // create render buffer and bind 16-bit depth buffer
    GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRb[0]);
    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, texW, texH);
}
```

This is my render to textue method:

```
   private void createSmokeTexture() {
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb[0]);
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.48f, 0.48f, 0.48f, 0.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0], 0);
    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRb[0]);
    //background counts
    renderscriptSmokeStep_involke();

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramSmoke);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramSmoke, "u_MVPMatrix");
    mMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramSmoke, "u_Move");
    mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramSmoke, "u_Texture");
    smokeParticleSizeUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramSmoke, "u_PointSize");
    maximumDensityHandler = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramSmoke, "u_MaximumDensity");

    cellDensityHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramSmoke, "a_Age");
    smokeStartPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramSmoke, "a_Position");

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mMoveMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mMoveMatrix, 0, positionX, positionY, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMoveMatrix, 0, Render.mModelMatrix, 0, mMoveMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniform1f(smokeParticleSizeUniformHandle, PARTICLE_SIZE);
    GLES20.glUniform1f(maximumDensityHandler, MAXIMUM_DENSITY);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMoveMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, Render.m2dProjectionMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particlePosBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(smokeStartPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(smokeStartPositionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(cellDensityHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(cellDensityHandle, 1, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, cellDensity);

    // Draw the point.
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, NUM_PARTICLES);
}
```

This gets called on draw:

```
   public void draw(){
    createSmokeTexture();
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    setTexture(renderTex[0]);
    drawSmokeToScreen();
}
```

asdas

```
    private void setTexture(int texture) {
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, texW, texH, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
}
```

And after this I draw it to the screen

```
   private void drawSmokeToScreen() {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    mMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_Move");
    positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Position");
    textureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_TexCoordinate");

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, Render.mModelMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, Render.m2dProjectionMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fullDrawSurfice.getPositionDataIndex());
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fullDrawSurfice.getTextureDataIndex());
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

Comment: One thing to check is the supported point size. Use `glGetFloatv(GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE, ...)`. Implementations are not required to support point sizes larger than 1. Other than that, people will probably not be able to help much with just a description of the problem. It could be a driver bug, or a problem in your code that just happens to not show any symptoms on other architectures.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Good to know that is not required, I checked and this device supports the it. You are right, I'll put in some code in a couple of minutes. And this is my I don't have experience developing on different architectures so I don't know what to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple of problems with the ordering of your calls.

1. At the start of `createSmokeTexture()`, there is this code sequence:

   ```
   GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb[0]);
   GLES20.glClearColor(0.48f, 0.48f, 0.48f, 0.0f);
   GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
           GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0], 0);
   GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
           GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRb[0]);
   ```

   Here, the framebuffer is cleared before it is completely set up by attaching the render targets with the `glFramebufferTexture2D()` and `glFramebufferRenderbuffer()` calls. This is most likely only a problem for the first frame, because at least in the code shown here, the render targets are never un-attached again. After that, the calls are just redundant. It would be much better to attach the render targets during setup.
2. At the end of `setTexture()`:

   ```
   GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, texW, texH, 0,
           GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
   ```

   Based on the sequence in `draw()`, this is called after the FBO rendering completed, and before using the resulting texture to draw to the main framebuffer. However, this `glTexImage2D()` call basically wipes out the content of the texture that was produced by the FBO rendering.

To fix both of these problems, remove the `glFramebufferTexture2D()` and `glFramebufferRenderbuffer()` from the first code sequence, and all but the `glActiveTexture()` and `glBindTexture()` calls from `setTexture()`. All of these should go to `setupRenderToTexture()` function, which then becomes:

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, renderTex, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0]);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, texW, texH, 0,
        GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

// create render buffer and bind 16-bit depth buffer
GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, depthRb, 0);
GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRb[0]);
GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, texW, texH);

GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fb, 0);
GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0], 0);
GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
        GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRb[0]);
```